# Use of echo >> produces inconsistent results

Tags: linux, bash, logging, echo

I've been trying to understand a problem that's cropped up with some of the scripts we use at work.

To generate many of our script logs, we utilize the `exec` command and file redirects to print all output from the script to both the terminal and a log file. Occasionally, for information that doesn't need to be displayed to the user, we do a straight redirect to the log file.

The issue we're seeing occurs on the last line of output to the file when we're printing the number of errors that occurred during that execution: *The text doesn't get printed to the file.*

In an attempt to diagnose the problem, I wrote a simplified version of our production script (script1.bash) and a test script (script2.bash) to try to tease out the problem.

**script1.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
log_name="${USER}_`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`_${HOST}_${1}.log"
log="/tmp/${log_name}"
log_tmp="/tmp/temp_logs"

err_count=0

finish()
{
   local ecode=0
   if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
      ecode=${1}
   fi

   # This is the problem line
   echo "Error Count: ${err_count}" >> "${log}"

   mvlog
   local success=$?

   exec 1>&3 2>&4

   if [ ${success} -ne 0 ]; then
      echo ""
      echo "WARNING: Failed to save log file to ${log_tmp}"
      echo ""
      ecode=$((ecode+1))
   fi

   exit ${ecode}
}

mvlog()
{
   local ecode=1

   if [ ! -d "${log_tmp}" ]; then
      mkdir -p "${log_tmp}"
      chmod 775 "${log_tmp}"
   fi

   if [ -d "${log_tmp}" ]; then
      rsync -pt --bwlimit=4096 "${log}" "${log_tmp}/${log_name}" 2> /dev/null
      [ $? -eq 0 ] && ecode=0

      if [ ${ecode} -eq 0 ]; then
         rm -f "${log}"
      fi
   fi
}

exec 3>&1 4>&2 >(tee "${log}") 2>&1

ecode=0

echo
echo "Some text"
echo

finish ${ecode}
```

**script2.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
runs=10000
logdir="/tmp/temp_logs"

if [ -d "${logdir}" ]; then
   rm -rf "${logdir}"
fi

for i in $(seq 1 ${runs}); do
   echo "Conducting run #${i}/${runs}..."
   ${HOME}/bin/script1.bash ${i}
done

echo "Scanning logs from runs..."

total_count=`find "${logdir}" -type f -name "*.log*" | wc -l`
missing_count=`grep -L 'Error Count:' ${logdir}/*.log* | grep -c /`

echo "Number of runs performed: ${runs}"
echo "Number of log files generated: ${total_count}"
echo "Number of log files missing text: ${missing_count}"
```

My first test indicated roughly 1% of the time the line isn't written to the log file. I then proceeded to try several different methods of handling this line of output.

1. Echo and Wait

```
echo "Error Count: ${err_count}" >> "${log}"
wait
```

2. Alternate print method

```
printf "Error Count: %d\n" ${err_count} >> "${log}"
```

3. No Explicit File Redirection

```
echo "Error Count: ${err_count}"
```

4. Echo and Sleep

```
echo "Error Count: ${err_count}" >> "${log}"
sleep 0.2
```

Of these, #1 and #2 each had a 1% fail rate while #4 had a staggering 99% fail rate. #3 was the only methodology that had a 0% fail rate.

At this point, I'm at a loss for why this behavior is occurring, so I'm asking the gurus here for any insight.

(Note that the simple solution is to implement #3, but I want to know *why* this is happening.)

Comment: As an aside, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern and probably try http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: `>(tee "${log}")` looks like the culprit; it runs a subprocess which may or may not get killed before your script exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, this looks like a race condition between your script and `tee`. It's generally better to avoid multiple programs writing to the same file at the same time.

If you do insist on having multiple writers, make sure they are all in append mode, in this case by using `tee -a`. Appends to the local filesystem are atomic, so all writes should make it (this is not necessarily true for networked file systems).